# PostgreSQL: Which is the better index order?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What index(es) would be most helpful for running many of these PostgreSQL queries?

```
SELECT id, pair_time, user1, user2 
FROM pairs 
WHERE ? in (user1, user2) 
ORDER by pair_time
```

? = arbitrary username specified at run time.

I was thinking these two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON pairs (user1, pair_time)
CREATE INDEX ON pairs (user2, pair_time)
```

But should the order be reversed?

```
CREATE INDEX ON pairs (pair_time, user1) 
CREATE INDEX ON pairs (pair_time, user2)
```

Is there a better solution requiring just one index?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if Postgres will use any of those indexes wisely on this query.

You might try this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM ((SELECT id, pair_time, user1, user2
       FROM pairs
       WHERE user1 = ?
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT id, pair_time, user1, user2
       FROM pairs
       WHERE user2 = ?
      )
     ) u
ORDER by pair_time;
```

This will use indexes on `pairs(user1)` and `pairs(user2)` for each subquery.  The outer `order by` will require sorting the data.  I cannot think of a way off-hand to remove the outer sort.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a [GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin.html) an an array of both columns:

```
create index on pairs using gin ((array[user1, user2]) array_ops);
```

Then change your query to use compare arrays:

```
select id, pair_time, user1, user2 
from pairs
where array[user1, user2] && array[1234]
order by pair_time
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regarding your below query

```
SELECT id, pair_time, user1, user2 FROM pairs WHERE ? in (user1, user2) ORDER by pair_time
```

below index will help better than others 2 index that you create

```
CREATE INDEX ON user_pairs (user1, pair_time)
CREATE INDEX ON user_pairs (user2, pair_time)
```